# NoMethodError: undefined method `methodname' for #<memory location>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I think I understand why this is happening, but I am not sure how to resolve the issue.

I will post the relevant code below.

```
class CoveragesController < ApplicationController
  def grab
    url = { 
      "cnn" => "http://www.cnn.com/", 
      "cnn_politics" => "http://www.cnn.com/POLITICS/",
    }

    url.each do |key, value|
      data = urlToString(value)
      appearances = countAppearances(data)
      @coverage = Coverage.create(
        :media        => key,
        :url          => value,
        :content      => data,
        :obama        => appearances["obama"],   
      )
    end
  end
end
```

What grab method does isn't that important. It is simply a method that uses multiple other methods to count the number of time "Obama" has been mentioned from CNN website.

In rails console, I attempted to run Coverage.grab. This is the error message I got.

```
1.9.3-p0 :003 > Coverage.grab
NoMethodError: undefined method `grab' for #<Class:0x007f9a5d813bf8>
    from /Users/jasonkim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/base.rb:1088:in `method_missing'
    from (irb):3
    from /Users/jasonkim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:45:in `start'
    from /Users/jasonkim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
    from /Users/jasonkim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:40:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Coverage.new works just fine by the way.

Also, when I configure route.rb, and create an address that runs grab method, it runs fine also.

I am guessing that when I run Coverage.grab, where isn't any instance of Coverage, for me to run "grab" method.

Any idea how I can fix this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At first, you define your method in `CoverageController`, not on `Coverage`
Second, you define an instance method which is thus only valid on an instance of the class. You can call it like this:

```
coverages_controller = CoveragesController.new
coverages_controller.grab
```

Comment: Thanks Holger Just and everyone else. Although Jordan and clyfe are correct in their responses, in the context of Rails, what Holger suggested seems to work best.

Comment: Rails controllers are not meant to be instantiated other than by the framework, and doing so is a bad thing imho. If you want to have the grab method in controllers maybe move it to ApplicationController at most (and call it via inheritance), but it's best to put it in it's own RemoteRequest class or similar, most probably a class method.

Comment: @clyfe Generally, you are right. Rails controllers are best used to be only called by the Rails router. But there are always exceptions from the rule. E.g. when you use service layers it (and don't take the name layer very serious) then it might make sense to directly instantiate and call a controller method. Though you have to make sure you don't use environment info like the `params` hash or sessions. So yeah, most of the time it's more sensible to build service layers or model abstractions outside of the usual ActiveRecord / ActionPack.

Answer (score 3):

`Coverage` and `CoverageController` aren't the same thing. You've defined `grab` as an instance method on the class `CoverageController` but you're trying to call `Coverage.grab`, a class method on the class `Coverage`.

If you want to be able to call `Coverage.grab` you would define it like this:

```
class Coverage < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.grab
    puts "foo"
  end
end

# Usage
>> Coverage.grab
=> foo
```

If you want `grab` to be an action in `CoverageController`, however, you've defined it correctly. But it's an instance method, not a class method--you can't call `CoverageController.grab` because `CoverageController` is the class itself, not an instance of the class, and there is no class method `grab`.

Generally you won't call methods directly on controllers--you leave this up to the router. You could try to instantiate an instance of CoverageController, e.g.:

```
>> @cc = CoverageController.new ...
>> @cc.grab
```

But this will fail unless you provide the same environment and parameters the router would.

Answer (score 2):

You defined the `grab` method as an instance method on the `CoveragesController` and then tried to call it as a class method on the `Coverages` class.

What you need to do is define it as a class method on the `Coverages` class.

```
class Coverages
  def self.grab
    # ...
  end
end
```